# How to use html tag inside a java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

[I want to display elements like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYJT0.png)  I'm creating an array and pushing some numbers into that array using javascript. After pushing a number I'm trying to use a html tag which displays that number inside a circle. But I'm facing trouble while doing that.

This is my javascript for pushing elements into array:

```
data.push(5);
data.push(6);
data.push(4);
```

Now the array will consists of the elements 5,6,4. Now I want to display these elements using some html tag.

The html tag I'm using to display these elements are:

```
<span class="w3-badge">5</span>
<span class="w3-badge">6</span>
<span class="w3-badge">4</span>
```

Then these elements will display in a circle. This is static because I'm giving numbers in the html tags.Actually I want to load these numbers using javascript.

I'm trying in this way,but it is not working:

```
"<span class="w3-badge">"data.push(5);"</span>"
"<span class="w3-badge">"data.push(6);"</span>"
"<span class="w3-badge">"data.push(5);"</span>"
```

Can Someone help me with this???

Comment: *Actually I want to load these numbers using javascript* - do you mean you want to create those badges using JS?

Comment: Yes! I want to create badges with these numbers. Which are user given.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply add those numbers to the `array` if you say it's something static, and then parse the `array` with a `for` loop to add the `HTML` tags? You need to correctly escape using the right quotes and concatenate:

```js
var test = [];
var data = [5, 6, 4];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  test += "<span class='w3-badge'>" + data[i] + "</span>";
}

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = test;
```

```html
<div id='container'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you filling this HTML with javascript?

```
"<span class=\"w3-badge\">" + data.push(5) + "</span>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use javascript to find the DOM elements and populate them. You will get to get the elements by class name and then loop through them to reassign the inner html.

```
var doms = getElementsByClassName( 'w3-badge' );
for( var i = 0; i < doms.length; i++ ) {
    doms[ i ].innerHTML = data[ i ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use javaScript

```
var test = "<span class='w3-badge'>"+data.push(5)+"</span>";
```

or the ES6 attempt, this will work inline

```
var test = `<span class='w3-badge'>${data.push(5)}</span>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged JQuery, here is a clean version which loops over every element with the class `w3-badge`:

```
var data = [];
data.push(5);
data.push(6);
data.push(4);
$('.w3-badge').each(function(i, obj) {
    document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = data[i];
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ceumdv3b/)

Snippet (with CSS Circle):

```js
var data = [];
data.push(5);
data.push(6);
data.push(4);
$('.w3-badge').each(function(i, obj) {
  document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = data[i];
});
```

```css
.cl {
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); 
    width: 36px; height: 36px;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="0" class="cl w3-badge">0</span>
<span id="1" class="cl w3-badge">0</span>
<span id="2" class="cl w3-badge">0</span>
```

---

**Pure JavaScript version:**
Note: You have to give every element an ID beginning from zero.
This isn't a that beautiful version but it works:

```
var data = [];
data.push(5);
data.push(6);
data.push(4);
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     console.log(i + " = " + data[i]);
     document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = data[i];
}
```

Demo:

```js
var data = [];
data.push(5);
data.push(6);
data.push(4);
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
 console.log(i + " = " + data[i]);
 document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = data[i];
}
```

```css
.cl {
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); 
    width: 36px; height: 36px;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span id="0" class="cl w3-badge">0</span>
<span id="1" class="cl w3-badge">0</span>
<span id="2" class="cl w3-badge">0</span>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jqcv4dtg/)

Answer (score 0):

To insert a DOM described as above into the HTML first do:

```js
var span1 = document.createElement("span");
span1.className = "w3-badge";
span1.innerHTML = 5; //create a span as above and set 5 between it
document.body.append(span1); //add completed span obj to document body
```

```html
<body></body>
```

You can also create a string `s` with the html code you want, and call

```
document.body.append(s);
```

to add the span to the body of the document

there are a lot of ways to get the values of DOMS as well.

most of them begin with `document.getElementsBy` and can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp)

each of these returns an array of all of the html doms that match your query.

`document.getElementById()` in particular will return one element only, since only one element should have a given id in the html. 
you can then call .innerHTML to a particular DOM selected with any of those methods
so in yours

```js
var data = [];
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("w3-badge");
for( var i =0; i < spans.length; i++){
    data.push(spans[i].innerHTML);
}
console.log(data);
```

```html
<span class="w3-badge">5</span>
<span class="w3-badge">6</span>
<span class="w3-badge">4</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

as you've tagged jquery, i will show you a jQuery way:

you must have a parent element, assuming it's a div with id "numbers", you could just:

```
var numbers = $('#numbers');

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    numbers.append($('<span class="w3-badge">'+data[i]+'</span>'));
}
```

With data.push(num) you push num to the next free index in the array.
With data[index] you get the value (num) at given index.

Next point:
You can't use unescaped double quotationmarks inside double quotationmarks.
Use single questionmarks instead of one of them.

And you have to use a + to connect two strings.

I think, you don't got the fundamental basics of Javascript.
You should work trough something like this before you start fiddling around: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics (~ 5-15 min reading)